# How to delete similar values and create new variables from a transpose result in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this data and and all variables except the Product_Code are duplicates. I'd like to create new variables like: Prod_,Prod_2....than transpose Product_Code for the new variables and eliminate the duplicates.

```
       ID    DATE        DAYS MONTH Product_Code
1  00003600B 2018-06-30  854   6    83648
2  00003600B 2018-06-30  854   6    40984
3  00003600B 2018-06-30  854   6    14534
4  00003600B 2018-06-30  854   6    18708
5  00003600B 2018-06-30  854   6    18710
```

I have trying the spread and transpose function and it didn't work.

```
spread(data = Tickets, key = ID, value = Product_Code)
```

I tried the transpose as well and it does't work well

```
Tickets.t = t(Tickets)
```

Any idea on how can I do this?

I expect something similar to this:

```
ID        DATA       DAYS MONTH PROD_1 PROD_2  PROD_3  PROD_4  PROD_5
00003600B 2018-06-30  854   6   83648   40984   14534   18708   18710
00003600B 2016-02-27  280   2   999195  999154  999339  0   0
00003600B 2015-05-23   77   5   999026  999339  999021  27640   999195
```

Comment: `spread` didn't work how?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make the new variable (PROD_n) before spreading. will there always be 5 or less PROD's per ID? Will it matter if (for example) '83648' is in PROD_1 once, and PROD_5 on an other ID?

Comment: Yes. I need to create at least 20 variables because The problem is that each  customer can buy more than one product on a date, so if a customer bought 5 products on the same date these five product codes will generate 5 lines, consequently the other variables of the dataset will be duplicated 5 times

Comment: ```df <- reshape(as.data.frame(table(dt_2)), idvar = c("data","dni"), timevar = "produto", direction = "wide"); ans <- df[!rowSums(df[,-c(1,2)])==0,]``` Just so you know that we are willing to help, but if you make your question a neat one, it's easier for us to help. Cheers and come back to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we need a sequence column.  Grouped by 'ID', 'DATE', 'DAYS', 'MONTH', create the 'PROD' column by concatenating the string 'PROD' with `row_number()` and then use that to `spread` the 'Product_Code' values

```
library(tidyverse)
Tickets %>%
  group_by(ID, DATE, DAYS, MONTH) %>% 
  mutate(PROD = str_c("PROD_", row_number())) %>% 
  spread(PROD, Product_Code)
# A tibble: 1 x 9
# Groups:   ID, DATE, DAYS, MONTH [1]
#  ID        DATE        DAYS MONTH PROD_1 PROD_2 PROD_3 PROD_4 PROD_5
#  <chr>     <chr>      <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 00003600B 2018-06-30   854     6  83648  40984  14534  18708  18710
```

#### data

```
Tickets <- structure(list(ID = c("00003600B", "00003600B", "00003600B", 
"00003600B", "00003600B"), DATE = c("2018-06-30", "2018-06-30", 
"2018-06-30", "2018-06-30", "2018-06-30"), DAYS = c(854L, 854L, 
854L, 854L, 854L), MONTH = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Product_Code = c(83648L, 
40984L, 14534L, 18708L, 18710L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: I get a error: Error: Evaluation error: could not find function "str_c". I'll try to figure out why it can't recognize  the str_c

Comment: @DecoPadaratz  It is from `stringr` which is also part of `tidyverse`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a variable that correspond to the product number before using spread.

```r
library(tidyverse)

Ticket %>%
   group_by(ID, DATE, DAYS, MONTH) %>%
   mutate(PROD = 1:n()) %>%
   spread(key = PROD, value = Product_code)
```